# How to call this.txt variable outside of the "reader.onload = function show (event)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get the this.txt variable outside of the function "reader.onload = function show (event)"..im trying to call this variable in here " .query" but i only get undefined value

```
 showFile(){
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
         var preview = document.getElementById('show-text');
         var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
         var reader = new FileReader()
         var textFile = /text.*/;
          var myArray = [];

         if (file.type.match(textFile)) {   
            reader.onload = function show (event) {
            //document.write(event.target.result); 
            myArray=(event.target.result.split('\n'))
            this.txt=myArray;
            alert(this.txt);
            }   
         }

            superagent.get('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1')
            .query({'key': this.apiKey,'num':10,'cx': this.cx ,'q':this.txt,'gl':'all'})
            .then((res) =>{

                console.log('value of show', this.show)
                console.log('response', res)
                let arr = res.body.items
            //   arr.map((value)=>{
            //      console.log('value', value)
            //      this.field =value
            //  })
                this.field = arr
                this.setState({
                    show: true
                })

            })
        reader.readAsText(file);
}
  }
```

Comment: Please provide additional Information on which variable you want to access in what scope?

Comment: Please check again René Carannante

Answer (score 0):

You need to either bind `showFile()` to the instance or use arrow form for it instead:

```
showFile = () => {
// code here
}
```

Comment: Yeah i did but it returns nothing..It only returns the array value when it within the function, when i try to call outside of the function or outside of the if statement it returns null(nothing).